# Graphing of thermodynamic processes

Tags: thermodynamics

Can someone please explain how to draw an irreversible isothermal curve vs a reversible isothermal curve starting from the same value of Pressure and volume and both expanding to double the volume on a P vs V graph

I am also having Difficulty in graphing the same for reversible vs irreversible adiabatic processes which are both expanding to double the volume

How would all the graphs compare if we drew them on the same graph?..this would help in determination of comparison of work done in these different processes

Comment: Can you please show us what you have so far?

Comment: I compared the slopes of isothermal and adiabatic reversible...finding that isothermal should be above adiabatic

Comment: In the case of an irreversible process, if the external pressure is held constant, the external pressure vs volume is flat.  In the case of a reversible process, the external pressure decreases as a function of increasing volume.

Comment: How would all the graphs compare to one another when drawn on a P vs V graph

Comment: The two constant-pressure irreversible graphs would be highest.  The constant temperature reversible graph would be in the middle, and the adiabatic reversible graph would be lowest.

Comment: Hold on but that constant pressure is only constant **external** pressure ...we are mapping pressure of the gas vs it's volume

Comment: In a gas (which is a Newtonian fluid), the force per unit area is not described by the ideal gas law in an irreversible compression or expansion; there is also a viscous contribution to the force per unit area.  Thus, the pressure calculated from the ideal gas law is not equal to the force per unit area.  However, the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the piston is always equal to the external pressure for a massless, frictionless piston, for both reversible and irreversible processes.

Comment: My teacher said that the order would be irreversible isothermal, reversible isothermal, irreversible adiabatic, reversible adiabatic

Comment: And that the reversible isothermal and irreversible isothermal graphs would be coincident

Comment: Also there were no lines parallel to the x axis

Comment: @ChetMiller Hi Chet. I have drafted an answer with diagrams to help, unless you want to do it. Let me  know

Comment: @Chet Miller Regarding the two irreversible processes being the highest couldn’t they just as well be the lowest if we chose to first drop the external pressure to the final value and then expand at constant external pressure until we reach final volume? That’s what we did last time for the adiabatic process

Comment: @Bob D. Oops.  You're right.  My bad.  On compression, the two irreversible processes would start out highest, and, on expansion, they would start out lower.  In both cases, they would probably cross over the reversibles if the final volumes are the same in all cases.

Comment: @BobD Yes, please present your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain how to draw an irreversible isothermal
>   curve vs a reversible isothermal curve starting from the same value of
>   Pressure and volume and both expanding to double the volume on a P vs
>   V graph

The top left diagram below shows a reversible isothermal process for an ideal gas where $pV=$ constant, together with an irreversible process, where the initial and final equilibrium states of both processes are the same. For both the pressure is halved, volume doubled, and the initial and final temperatures are the same.

The reversible process is carried out very slowly so that the gas temperature and pressure are in equilibrium with the surroundings at all times during the process. The work done by the gas is the area under the PV curve. Since there is no change in temperature, and since the change in internal energy for an ideal gas depends only on temperature ($\Delta U=C_{v}\Delta T$) there is no change in internal energy. The work done during the expansion exactly equals the heat added per the first law ($Q=W$).

For the irreversible  process the external pressure is abruptly halved and the gas allow to expand at constant external pressure until the volume doubles, at which point further expansion is prevented and the gas is allowed to reach equilibrium with the surroundings by virtue of heat transfer. It is important to note that although the initial and final temperatures are the same, the process is not truly "isothermal" since, unlike the reversible process, the gas temperature is not constant throughout the process until the end. Note that the work done (area under the constant pressure line) is less than that done by the reversible process.

> I am also having Difficulty in graphing the same for reversible vs
>   irreversible adiabatic processes which are both expanding to double
>   the volume

The top right diagram shows a reversible and irreversible adiabatic process.

The reversible process is shown for doubling the volume as you asked. But because the process is governed by the equation $pV^{k}=$ constant the pressure will be less than for the isothermal process for the same final volume. Note that the work done for a reversible adiabatic process will be less than that for a reversible isothermal process. That's because the work done in an adiabatic process comes as the expense of the internal energy of the gas. For the isothermal process, the work done is due to heat transfer from the surroundings. The bottom diagram shows the two reversible processes together with the same initial state, and the same final volume.

The irreversible adiabatic process is carried out similar to irreversible isothermal process by halving the pressure and allowing the gas to expand at constant external pressure. When the process reaches the same volume as the reversible process, state 2, the gas is not yet in equilibrium as its internal pressure is still greater than the external applied pressure. Since the gas is unable to transfer heat to the surroundings to reduce the pressure, it needs to continue to expand to until its internal pressure is in equilibrium with the external pressure at state 2a.

In the order of work done, we have (1) reversible isothermal, (2) reversible adiabatic, (3) irreversible isothermal, (4) irreversible adiabatic.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Unable to see the image